# tab bar xcode remove title of bar item with storyboards

Tags: xcode, customization, uitabbar, uistoryboard, uitabbaritem

I would to remove a title of the bar item and show only the images also in the space of the title (size of the image 60x60 not 30x30)
its possibile only wih storyboards or IB ?

thanks a lot